# Combining if statements and multiple sql queries into one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a server where it limits the amount of sql queries you can make per hour, so I'm trying to find a way to combine all 3 of my if statements and sql queries into one sql query, and am wondering if that's possible? Please take a look at my code:

```
$text1 = "one";
$text2 = "two";
$text3 = "three";

$data = SELECT text FROM tableName WHERE 
text LIKE '%$text1%' AND
text LIKE '%$text2%' AND
text LIKE '%$text3%' order by rand() limit 1;

if ($data == null) {
$data = SELECT text FROM tableName WHERE 
text LIKE '%$text1%' AND
text LIKE '%$text2%' order by rand() limit 1;
}

if ($data == null) {
$data = SELECT text FROM tableName WHERE 
text LIKE '%$text1%' order by rand() limit 1;
}
```

Comment: I HIGHLY recommend not creating queries by string bashing. You open yourself to all sorts of SQL injection problems later. Prepare a parametrized statement instead.

Comment: @TrippKinetics Nah, I didn't show it, but I actually clean the inputs before I use it in the sql queries. Escape apostrophes, quotation marks, escape symbol, strip tags, ect.

Comment: Even if you are sanitizing your inputs, I would still suggest using prepared statements. Just in case you missed something in your sanitizer.

Comment: @TrippKinetics Prepare statements seems kind of complicated to use though.

Comment: Not even slightly. You just prepare the statement and then execute the prepared statement object rather than executing the statement strong directly. Read up on it. It will save you a lot of hassle in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT text,
((text LIKE '%$text1%') + (text LIKE '%$text2%') + (text LIKE '%$text3%')) as `matches` 
FROM tableName 
HAVING `matches` > 0
ORDER BY `matches` DESC, rand() LIMIT 1
```

This should sort the values by the number of matches as each expression will be treated as integer 1 on a match or 0 otherwise.

Comment: I only want it to get it if the $data returns as null. If the first if statement got something, I don't want it to execute the other 2 if statements to make sure the results as accurate.

Comment: So if this statement got something, I don't want the other 2 statements to execute to get less accurate results, with the OR statements. (text LIKE '%$text1%' AND
text LIKE '%$text2%' AND
text LIKE '%$text3%')

Comment: My update should be a better solution for your needs.

Comment: Can I subsitute HAVING with a WHERE clause instead?

Comment: Or have something like, WHERE HAVING?

Comment: Why would you need a where clause?  Having is required with a calculated field / alias.

Comment: Just tried it out. It worked out more perfectly than I thought it would. This is pure genius. I really appreciates it.